# GsonBuilder Not Found after adding dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I'm building an app with Kotlin in Android Studio and I am trying to implement GsonBuilder but I'm getting an `Unresolved reference: GsonBuilder`. However, I have already added the dependency to the .gradle file using `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'` and I imported it into the page with `import com.google.gson.Gson`. Below is the implementation in my code:

```
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val device = gson.fromJson(body, Devices::class.java)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println(e)
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
```

I'm still really new to Kotlin and Android Studio, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder` ?

Comment: ...Well that was easy. Thanks, for some reason I though that GsonBuilder was included in the Gson library